# ng-repeat não mostra valores em branco

Tags: angularjs

tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca por motivo" ng-model="search.motivo" >

<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.listaDesbloqueio | filter:search">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checkbox" /></td>
                        <td>{{item.data | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.hora | formatTime}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.motivo}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

porém quando apago todas as letras no campo de busca, não é exibido os registros com motivo em branco ou nulo, alguém saberia como fazer para que seja exibido os registros com branco ou nulo no motivo?

Answer (score 0):

Para isso é necessário um botão para redefinir seu objeto de pesquisa para nulo, já que ao preenchê-lo ele ganha um valor:

```
<button data-ng-click="search = null">Limpar</button>
```